# jQuery in update panel not successfully adding cssclass after panel refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, wizard-control

I have a div, which when clicked, displays a hidden asp:textbox via the following jQuery.

```
      function BindEvents() {
          $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#showtextbox").click(function () {  
                 $("#TextBox1").removeClass("hidden"); 
                 $("#TextBox1").addClass("showInline");  
      });
```

This works fine, except after the update panel is refreshed. After it is refreshed, when clicking “showtextbox” the textbox remains hidden. I know that the jQuery is running because it is hit when debugging. Here is my code.

```
  <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript">
              Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);
        </script>
   </ContentTemplate>

   <asp:textbox runat="server" id="TextBox1"  CssClass="hidden" /> <span id=”showtb8”/>
```

Any ideas what’s going on here? How can I make the textbox visible after the update panel is refreshed? I thought that after adding it to the Sys.Application.add_load it would work, but it doesn't. This is also in a wizard control if that make a difference.

*I should note, that this same logic works fine when showing and hiding a regular div. It just is not working with the asp:textbox.

Comment: Is the showInline class added to #TextBox1?

Comment: @roasted No, it's not.

Comment: "I know that the jQuery is running because it is hit when debugging." That means that the click event is fired, right? Or i misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, the click event is fired.

Comment: And what give you in click handler: $("#TextBox1").length ???  I don't use asp but i heard it can change some attribute as id.

Comment: the id is not changed, and i do not have a value for .length

Comment: You mean $("#TextBox1").length returns 0? If yes, that means that this element doesn't exist. Could you post rendered html code (client side)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30846/discussion-between-jack28-and-roasted)

Answer (score 0):

after ajax calls the event bindings are lost if you use regular bindings.
try the `on` function of jquery.

```
         $("#showtextbox").on('click',function () {  
             $("#TextBox1").removeClass("hidden"); 
             $("#TextBox1").addClass("showInline");  
          });
```

Comment: Well, if i understand your statement, you are not even using delegation here

Comment: @user1 the on function is giving me the same results

Comment: can you firebug and check the id of the button after rendering? If the button is inside a control or a masterpage, it changes id.

Comment: The id of the "button" stays the same after rendering.