# Run Javascript after C# Update panel Refresh

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm using a masked input plugin to control entry of fields (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)..

This is working very well ... until I added my update panel and boom no more masked input after update .. I have my scripts all in the page. Reading [jQuery in update panel not successfully adding cssclass after panel refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817115/jquery-in-update-panel-not-successfully-adding-cssclass-after-panel-refresh) I also tried [Running Javascript after update panel refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844061/running-javascript-after-update-panel-refresh) but this doesn't work either..

it looks as though event bindings are lost.. How can get my script to run to re-add the input masks after update panel update?

```
script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#Curr_Mileage").mask("9?99999");
        $("#Litres").mask("99.9");
        $("#ordno").mask("aa99999");
        $("#litre2").mask("99.9");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: are all these controls inside  update panel?

Comment: [you tried this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190549/how-can-i-run-some-javascript-after-an-update-panel-refreshes) ?

Comment: yes all the controls are inside the update panel. The script I placed in the head

Comment: SID M.. Thanks...this fixed it <script> 
   ///<summary>
   ///  This will fire on initial page load, 
   ///  and all subsequent partial page updates made 
   ///  by any update panel on the page
   ///</summary>
   function pageLoad(){ alert('page loaded!') }  
</script>

Comment: so should i post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script> 
   function pageLoad(){ 
       jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#Curr_Mileage").mask("9?99999");
        $("#Litres").mask("99.9");
        $("#ordno").mask("aa99999");
        $("#litre2").mask("99.9");
    });
 }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to create obj of `PageRequestManager` and call your jquery after update panel updated
and make sure this script block should be outside update panel

```
<script>
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);



    function pageLoaded() {

        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#Curr_Mileage").mask("9?99999");
            $("#Litres").mask("99.9");
            $("#ordno").mask("aa99999");
            $("#litre2").mask("99.9");
        });

    }

</script>
```

Comment: thanks I've tried this but no joy. The masks do not apply even when the page is first loaded using above

Comment: simple pageload function works great.. Thanks everyone..              script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            jQuery(function ($) {
                $("#Curr_Mileage").mask("9?99999");
                $("#Litres").mask("99.9");
                $("#ordno").mask("aa99999");
                $("#litre2").mask("99.9");
            });
        }  
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

```
         Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(myFunc);

    function myFunc () {
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#Curr_Mileage").mask("9?99999");
    $("#Litres").mask("99.9");
    $("#ordno").mask("aa99999");
    $("#litre2").mask("99.9");
});
```

}

Comment: thanks I've tried this but same as below. The masks do not apply even when the page is first loaded using above

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you.

Managing partial-page updates of server UpdatePanel controls in the browser.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311028(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311028%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)